# AppCode build for profiling equivalent

Tags: c++, appcode

Is there an equivalent for Xcode's  `Product > Build for > Profiling` in AppCode? Or does this have to be done in Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AppCode you can just click Profile button and the app will be build automatically:

[image: profile in AppCode]